# unresolved external symbol error when use ICE in Visual Studio

Tags: ice

I used ICE(www.zeroc.com/ice.html) in visual studio 2010, had already included the "include" and "lib" directories, however failed to build the project.
errors like these:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol.
fatal error LNK1120: 111 unresolved externals.
```

Any suggestions and help?

Comment: Problem solved! forgot to add dependency libs: iced.lib & iceutild.lib